# Variable scope and addEventlistener

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, addeventlistener

I would be grateful if someone can explain this: Why in the below code the console.log(array) within the addEventlistener can retrieve the array content (while not the console.lo(array) outside the addEventlistener)

```js
const input = document.getElementById('search')
let array = []
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(resp=>resp.json())
.then(data=>{
    array = data.map(user => {
    return { name: user.name, email: user.email}
    });
})

console.log(array)

input.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
    console.log(array)
})
```

So why the addEventListener is capable of retrieving data within the array and not the console.log above? thank you.

Comment: Because the `console.log(array)` *outside* is called **before** `array` is assigned the new value. See also my own post [here](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html).

Comment: This is because of the difference between the execution of asynchronous and synchronous code.
Your fetch call is asynchronous and is not completed at the time you call console.log(array). Your console.log for the addEventListener works, because the code that you define as second parameter is a callback function. This function is just defined at this place but gets executed later on. More precisely it gets executed every time the user does an input. So when this code gets executed your fetch promise is already fulfilled and your array is not empty anymore.

Comment: Thank you guys for your clarifications. Now kind of understand.